# Can't install angular/cli propely?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, node-modules

**I had uninstalled all node modules and reinstall but still problem is not solved ?**

To uninstall 
`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`

To install again
`npm install -g @angular/cli`

I had uninstalled nodejs from control panel also and reinstalled also.

[image: Here is my problem !]

Comment: Angular cli is a global module, try installing with -g parameter

Answer (score 0):

To reinstall a global module (`-g`), you need `-g`.

So, the command pair either needs to be `npm uninstall @angular/cli && npm install @angular/cli` or `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli && npm install -g @angular/cli`. You're mixing the two.

Comment: I had installed using this commmand `npm install -g @angular/cli`
by mistake I wrote `npm install @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0):

First You uninstall the old version of the CLI globally, cleared cache, and then installed the new version CLI globally, following these instructions:

- `npm uninstall -g angular-cli`
- `npm cache clean`
- `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Answer (score -1):

This problem comes because of Latest Version of Nodejs.

**DO INSTALL LTS VERSION OF NODEJS**